# How to get test coverage of tests in different repo using jacoco?

Tags: java, automation, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am very new to this arena.
I am trying to get the test coverage of my automation test cases written under a completely different repo for the tests using Jacoco.
I want to know if it is possible at first place ? And if it is how to achieve it?
There is separate repo used by the developers for the application source code.
How is it possible to get the test coverage when both source code and tests are in different repos 
The unit tests coverage is received by developers.
How can testers get the coverage for their integration tests?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  `How can testers get coverage` Usually developers write tests and testers execute them.  There should be a test plan/written documentation, or you might have to just ask.  Alternately, some dev houses have the testers write their own tests.  You should definitely have a written plan in that case, and you should have people you can ask for help if you don't understand what your team's plan is (start with your manager, I'd say).

Comment: Developers will get the coverage from the unit tests that they have written for their code. I am curious to know if testers can also test the coverage of their tests and way to do it. Anyway one way through the documentation level is that how many manual test cases are being automated. And I have that in place. I will still modify the question to add more clarity. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CI/CD tool like Jenkins? In that case, you can schedule different builds for different branches in that if you have admin access to the tool.

**Edited after seeing the request of John.**

Usually, companies will have DevOps admin and other stakeholders of the project who monitor what is happening in each branch. There will be a branching strategy for each Product team. You need to periodically merge contents from developer branch to test branch so that the jacoco test coverage reports don't look confusing to your Dev team members. When, how and what is merged will be decided by the stakeholders and it depends on a lot of facts starting right from the software development process.

If you are following Scrum methodology for software development, at the end of each sprint, developers would give a demo on testable new features or enhancements. Testing team will create test cases based on what is delivered. All these happens in the Sprint review/retrospective/demo meetings.

If you need more information on Jenkins and configuring multiple jobs on them, you need to look at a separate stackexchange forum dedicated to devops. I believe [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/175/how-to-rebuild-multiple-jobs-at-the-same-time-in-jenkins) should be a good place to start for you.

Comment: We have Jenkins for CI. Can you please elaborate ?